# Geometric series with binomial coefficients

Tags: geometric-series

Please sum this sum , $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{r+a+bk}{a+bk} x^{bk}$.
Where r ,a and b are fixed integers

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Do you have any reason to expect a closed form?

Comment: I had tried with change of variables and now I have done it. Thank you for the comment sir.